# Template for a two sided, double parallel fold document A6 portrait

Tags: print-production, template

From several articles and posts I have read, the margins for the folds would not be evenly spaced so that the brochure can be tucked into itself.  I have not been able to find a template showing where those fold lines would typically be (and thus what the size of my panels should be).

My goal is a brochure that, when folded, will be A6 in size and portrait orientation.

[image: Double parallel fold]

Comment: @BillyKerr - I mean double-parallel fold, and have added an image. Not z-fold or gate-fold.  Will update with orientation information.

Comment: OK, but what's stopping you from taking a sheet of paper, folding it yourself, and measuring where the folds are?  Then you could create your own template. Also, that (F) shape in your diagram is the wrong aspect ratio for A6

Comment: @BillyKerr - I know the shape is off, it is an exemplar of the type of fold.  As I said, I can't seem to find a template to show what the actual size or ratio of the inner folds would be.

Comment: I don't know if this can be answered since it probably depends on how thick the paper/card is.  Best way to do it is to create a mock up and fold it yourself and measure it with a ruler.

Comment: @BillyKerr - I hadn't thought about the paper aspect.  That is true, it probably varies from stock to stock.  I will just delete the question rather than adding noise and clutter to the site.

Comment: Guess I can't close it as there is an answer.  Points to Lucian and thanks for the help/suggestions @BillyKerr.

Comment: I don't think you need to delete it. The question is a valid one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be constructed using simple math, 4xA6 portrait fold means a canvas size of 420x148mm, then reduce the inner flaps a bit. However the best thing to do is contact whoever will be printing this first. They should be able to get you a template or tell you exact dimensions for each fold, since this depends on their machines and paper thickness.

Comment: I appreciate the answer.  I actually met with the printer and they could not give me directions as to the fold positioning.  That is why I was posting here.  I will admit there is a language barrier between myself and the printer so that could be part of the issue.  As far as I understand, the inner folds need to be slightly offset so that it is flush when folded and so it is not just a case of dividing the dimensions in 4.

Comment: Skip this printer and move to a different one. They should know how their machines work with whatever paper is selected, so you can only assume the adjustments you need to make. Whatever you adjust, you cannot anticipate if that can be produced or not by a certain printer. The printer needs to guide you through this or just change to an easier to fold format. Nobody here can guess what your printer can actually produce.